# Error with uncommitted transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that I ran in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1] 
BEGIN TRY
    UPDATE SomeTable 
    SET value = 0 
    WHERE username = 'test' 
       OR [PR_RequestDate] < DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE())

    INSERT INTO SomeTable (username, value) 
    VALUES('test', 'test')

    COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1]
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1]
END CATCH  
GO
```

After executing it every other query that I try to run on the same table runs forever, and when I try to exist SQL Server Management Studio, I get a warning that there are uncommitted transactions.

What exactly is wrong with my query and how should I fix it?

Comment: `INSERT INTOSomeTable (username, value) VALUES('test', 'test')` is that typo there in your actual code? My guess is something bad happens which aren't caught by CATCH (maybe the above typo), so you'll never reach commit nor rollback. CATCH doesn't catch everything (can be confusing).
So after your CATCH try adding a @@TRANCOUNT

Comment: Is even your select query runs forever?

Comment: You are hiding yourself information about "what is wrong". At least print error message in your catch block if you don't want it to be raised for some reason.

Comment: Since you seem to be running `UPDATE` as well as `INSERT INTO` same table, within the same transaction, I suspect some kind of locking. Run `sp_whoisactive` in another query window and see what is going on

Comment: ``INTOSomeTable`` should be  ``INTO SomeTable``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typos will be caught immediately,further as per Ivan suggestionmyou are not showing us entire info.You are getting uncommitted transactions error  due to error in update or insert and the entire query trying to rollback..You can do the follow to get total message and trancount,,

```
set xact_abort on--to rollback entire batch,rollback in catch is redundant
begin try
begin tran
commit
end try
begin catch
select @@trancount--gives me number of open transactions
select error_message()
rollback tran
end catch
```

Comment: Hi, Running the `update` and `insert` statements on their own produces no errors. I implemented what you are suggesting and it seems to be going ok. But basically what changed is the `GO` statement. Why would that create this issue.

Comment: Go is a batch seperator,i am not sure of the context of go in this question